# Laravel 5 lists htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following:

\App\Models\Finance\FinanceAccount::lists('name', 'id')

At the top of one of my views but it keeps giving me the error:

```
htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: mysite\views\modals\add.blade.php)
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

That makes sense about it being an array, I put it into a select and it's working now:

```
<div class="form-group">
      {!!Form::label('Account')!!}
      {!!Form::select('account', \App\Models\Finance\FinanceAccount::getSelectOptions(), 1, ['class' => 'form-control'])!!}
  </div>
```

Is there a way to set the namespace for views, so I don't have to type the full namespace all the time?

Comment: Post view code please? possibly with a var_dump of what the variable passed to htmlentities contains. Above htmlentities call var_dump ( $var ); die;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`lists` gives an array and that's not something you can echo out with `{{ }}`. What you need to do is to loop or `implode` the array if you want to print it's content.

With `foreach`

```
@foreach ($list as $item)
    {{ $item }}<br />
@endforeach
```

With [`implode`](http://php.net/function.implode)

```
{{ implode(', ', $list) }}
```

With `Form::select`

```
{!! Form::select('foo', $list) !!}
```

---

If you don't want to use your namespace (which you never should) in your view, [send the data](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views#basic-usage) from your controller to your view file.

If you have this in your controller

```
public function foo() {
    $baz = \App\Models\Finance\FinanceAccount::getSelectOptions();

    return view('bar', compact('baz'));
}
```

The `$baz` variable is then available in your view file. So you can do this:

```
{!! Form::select('foo', $baz) !!}
```

Comment: Thanks @marwelln.. you saved my time. +1

Comment: Great answer. That processing should be handled in controller and then passed to view. Amen!