# Laravel htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to fetch data from a table by using a custom class .But it says htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string.

This is My DateTimeFormat Class .Here vitals is a table.which have vita_name attribute.

```
public static function get_vital_details($vital_id)
{
      $result = DB::table('vitals')
       ->select('vita_name')
       ->where(['id' => $vital_id])
       ->get();
    return $result;
}
```

This is the view i am trying to access the data .

```
    <?php $vitalsinfo=DateTimeFormat::get_vital_details($vitaldetails->vital_id) ?>

   @foreach($vitalsinfo as $vitalsinfo)

   {{$vitalsinfo}}

   @endforeach
```

i Am new to laravel .Any suggestions would be more than welcome. Thank You

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29059160/laravel-5-lists-htmlentities-expects-parameter-1-to-be-string

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to dipslay object as string, so try to use `first()` instead of `get()` to get just one object instead of collection:

```
$result = DB::table('vitals')
            ->select('vita_name')
            ->where(['id' => $vital_id])
            ->first();
```

And do just this (instead of `@foreach` construction) to display property of an object:

```
{{ $vitalsinfo->vita_name }}
```